# UIImagePickerControllerDelegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4

I have a standalone class to fetch an image from the camera/photo library using UIImagePickerController.

I cannot seem to figure out why the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo or the imagePickerControllerDidCancel methods are not called..? I realise this question has been asked many times but I cannot figure it out... I know that all the method names are correct.

I have properly set all of the following in the info.plist:

- Privacy - Media Library Usage Description
- Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
- Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

---

```
import UIKit

class ImagePickerService: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  fileprivate var completion: ((UIImage) -> ())
  fileprivate var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController

  init(completion: @escaping ((UIImage) -> ())) {
    self.completion = completion
    self.imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    super.init()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
  }

  func show(from viewController: UIViewController) {
    showAlert(from: viewController)
  }

  fileprivate func showAlert(from viewController: UIViewController) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take a photo", style: .default) { _ in
      self.openCamera(from: viewController)
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choose from library", style: .default) { _ in
      self.openGallery(from: viewController)
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // MARK: Image Picker

  fileprivate func openCamera(from viewController: UIViewController) {
    guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) else {
      viewController.showOKAlert(title: "Error!", message: "No camera available")
      return
    }
    showImagePicker(withSource: .camera, from: viewController)
  }

  fileprivate func openGallery(from viewController: UIViewController) {
    showImagePicker(withSource: .photoLibrary, from: viewController)
  }

  fileprivate func showImagePicker(withSource source: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, from viewController: UIViewController) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = source
    viewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}

extension ImagePickerService {

  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage else {
      return
    }
    completion(image)
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

---

**EDIT:**
The problem was that I was not creating a strong reference to the ImagePickerService on instantiation and it was released automatically before the delegate methods could be called.

Comment: How are you using the `ImagePickerService`? Are you instantiating it and keeping a strong reference to it?

Comment: You should set the imagePicker navigation controller delegate : `imagePicker.navigationController?.delegate = self`

Comment: @silicon_valley That was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the following code snippet:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage else {
      return
    }
    completion(image)
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You are expecting that there is always an edited image, which may not be the case for all photos in your photo library. Try using the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key instead when `info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]` returns `nil`.

If these methods aren't called in the first place, you need to make sure you have a strong reference to the `ImagePickerService` instance.

For example, this code works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var picker: ImagePickerService?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) { [weak self] in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            self.picker = ImagePickerService() { (image) in
                print(image)
            }
            self.picker?.show(from: self)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you keeping a strong reference to the `ImagePickerService` instance?

Comment: Yep, wasn't keeping a strong reference to the instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a singleton of the ImagePickerService Class :

```
static let shared = ImagePickerService()
```

After creating the singleton the reference to the service object will maintain and it will not be released.

Set the **delegate** in init() and make a method to show ImagePicker.

```
func pickMedia(from: UIViewController?,didPickMedia: ((UIImage) -> ())?){      
            //self.openCamera()
            //or
            //self.openGallery()
}
```

From that singleton you can present it as :

```
  ImagePickerService.shared.pickMedia(from: self) { (image) in

  }
```